# what is correct result after FFT, if input array is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

Tags: fft

can anyone tell me what is correct result after Fast Furier Transform, if input array is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.

I got {28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}. It isn't correct right?

just want to test FFT implementation in C.

thanks,
Andrey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct answer to a FFT for `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` is

```
{28.0000 + 0.0000i, 
-4.0000 + 9.6569i,
-4.0000 + 4.0000i,
-4.0000 + 1.6569i,
-4.0000 + 0.0000i, 
-4.0000 - 1.6569i,
-4.0000 - 4.0000i,
-4.0000 - 9.6569i}
```

Comment: Note that there is more than one "correct" answer and this is just one of them - there are at least 3 different ways of dealing with scaling factors.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't correct (a single non-zero output element implies that your input consists of either a constant value, or a single complex-exponential component).

Why don't you use an existing FFT implementation, such as [*FFTW*](http://www.fftw.org/) to provide a reference result?  Or just implement a straightforward DFT?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fft%5B0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7%5D) it's:

[image]

Note that there is no single "correct answer" as there is more than one definition of the DFT/FFT, the difference between each one being what scaling factor you include for forward and inverse transform. (The difference between this answer and the earlier accepted answer is just a scaling factor of `sqrt(8)`).

Comment: Where is the scaling factor coming from?

Comment: @Rekin: as I mentioned above, there are at least 3 different ways of defining DFT and IDFT when it comes to scaling factor. You can scale by 1, sqrt(N) or N for each direction.

Comment: Ok. Do you know of any advantages of having DFT scaled by the factor? Like, it seems to me the Factor and InverseFactor (the WolframAlpha functions) give the same results. Could it be because of the scaling?

Comment: Yes, it really doesn't matter - it's just a convention - you just need to know which scaling factors your particular FFT implementation uses.

Answer (score 0):

*Divij answer assumes that input {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} has size=8, that is:*

{0,0i},{1,0i},{2,0i},{3,0i},{4,0i},{5,0i},{6,0i}

*for input considered as binary complex with size=4, that is:*

{0,1i},{2,3i},{4,5i},{6,7i},
**the result is:**

```
{12, 16i}
{-8, 0i}
{-4, -4i}
{0, -8i}
```